# How to count and percentage from csv file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have 3gb csv file and How to count duplicate URLs and percentages

is the sum to calculate the percentage?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/url_all/auguesturl.csv",names=['URL','Count'])
dd = df.groupby(
    df.columns.tolist(),
    as_index=False
).size().sort_values(ascending=False).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum(),axis=1)
# percentage
# ss = df.groupby('Count').size() / df.groupby('Count').size().sum()
print(dd)
```

my output is:

```
setup.iclo.com:443  8354271
da.ds-int.net:443   7278819
```

I like the output like this

```
URL                          Count      Percentage
googleads.g.doubl.net:443   1,314,530   2.1 
s.yimg.com:443              986,275     1.6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need aggregate `sum` of column `Count` and for new column divide by total:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'URL': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','c','d'],
    'Count': list(range(9))
})
print (df)
  URL  Count
0   a      0
1   a      1
2   a      2
3   a      3
4   b      4
5   b      5
6   b      6
7   c      7
8   d      8

df1 = df.groupby('URL', as_index=False)['Count'].sum()
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Count'] / df1['Count'].sum()
df1 = df1.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
print (df1)
  URL  Count  Percentage
1   b     15    0.416667
3   d      8    0.222222
2   c      7    0.194444
0   a      6    0.166667
```

But if need count `URL` values use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) or [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df['URL'].value_counts().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['URL','Count']
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Count'] / df1['Count'].sum()
```

Alternative:

```
df1 = df.groupby('URL').size().reset_index(name='Count')
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Count'] / df1['Count'].sum()
df1 = df1.sort_values('Count', ascending=False)
```

---

```
print (df1)
  URL  Count  Percentage
0   a      4    0.444444
1   b      3    0.333333
2   d      1    0.111111
3   c      1    0.111111
```

Comment: thanks you its working and Is not it similar to 1.2 percentage ?

Comment: @KatarinaAlves - Do you need `df1['Percentage'] = (df1['Count'] / df1['Count'].sum()).mul(100).round(1)` ?